# Update Object Properties Through Reflection Based On Property Name

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have a custom class with approximately 30 properties. (I.E. headername, headersize...)

I would like to be able to update a property by the name of the property as a string.

I am looking at using reflection (not 100% sure if this is the best method) instead of a large case statement that would continuously need to be updated if I add to the main object.

Through things I have found I have created the following Sub. I have put this in another location than the class of the object.

```
Public Sub UpdateValue(ByRef MainData As FilesMainData, ByVal SearchForObjectPartName As String, ByVal NewValue As Object)
    Dim ObjectPartTypes() As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = MainData.GetType().GetProperties()
    Dim ObjectPartNames() As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = MainData.GetType().GetFields()

    For I As Integer = 0 To ObjectPartNames.Count - 1
        If ObjectPartTypes(I).Name.Equals(SearchForObjectPartName) Then
            ObjectPartTypes(I).SetValue(ObjectPartTypes(I).GetType, NewValue,CType(I, Object) )
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

1) I am getting some errors and know the code isn't right, but am unsure how to fix
2) I am unsure it's in the correct location.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It can work, but the resulting code wont be any easier to read and slower (you *are* looping thru 30+ props to set *one).  In the end, wont you just be calling that thing 30 times instead of just setting the property?

Comment: I am working towards hands off on this project. I want to setup for easier updating in the future. If they need to add .HeaderLastUpdated for example, they can just add the property and the saving/loading of the data will just happen with adding the property. This is a very fluid project that I want to simplify maintenance.

Comment: how is `myObject.NewProperty = newValue` significantly more labor instensive than `UpdateValue(myObject, propName, propValue)`?  Boxing everything as `Object` makes the code more vulnerable to bugs because there arent any datatype checks.  Anyway, is there a question here?  If you want help with "some errors"  you will have to clue us in to what they are

Comment: Current error (been working on it while discussing) and the conversion is causing a problem I believe

error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object[]'.

line: ObjectPartTypes(I).SetValue(ObjectPartTypes(I).GetType, NewValue, CType(I, Object))

I believe it's being caused by the CType call

Comment: Please [Edit] your code with the relevant details...`I` is just your loop iterator though

Comment: The code is what i'm currently running. I'm using I in the for loop.

Comment: First issue is with `ObjectPartNames(I)`, this returns a FieldInfo class and you cannot use .Equals directly against it. I believe you want the .Name property. ie, `ObjectPartNames(I).Name.Equals(...`

Comment: Sorry I forgot I changed that as well. I've been tooling with stepping through it, and finally got the If working, and get to the actual setvalue line, which is where that error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code:

1. You want to update the properties, but when iterating through the loop you are using the wrong count
2. Also you are using SetValue incorrectly, the first parameter must be the instance of the object containing the property

Here's the update method:

```
Public Sub UpdateValue(ByRef MainData As FilesMainData, ByVal SearchForObjectPartName As String, ByVal NewValue As Object)
    Dim ObjectPartTypes() As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = MainData.GetType().GetProperties()
    For I As Integer = 0 To ObjectPartTypes.Count - 1
        If ObjectPartTypes(I).Name.Equals(SearchForObjectPartName) Then
            ObjectPartTypes(I).SetValue(MainData, NewValue)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```